# Markdown: Displaying figures in collapsed section

Tags: markdown

When I want to include a collapsed section in markdown as follows

```
<details>
  <summary>Click to expand!</summary>
  
  I'd like to show an image here, for like this:

<center>![](example.jpg)</center>

</details>
```

However the image does not appear until I remove the `<details>` part again. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it. Firstly you need to add four spaces before all those tages and newlines before and after the block. Secondly you can add image differently:

```html
    <details>
    <summary>click to expand</summary>
    <IMG src="blob:https://dev.azure.com/..."  alt="image.png"/>
    </details>
```

Answer (score 0):

Markdown does not offer collapsable sections itself!
Take a look at this question that explain how to get collapsable headers in markdown:

[Collapsible header in Markdown to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562552/collapsible-header-in-markdown-to-html)